# Shortcut for echo "<pre>";print_r($myarray);echo "</pre>";

Tags: php

Is there a Shortcut for

```
echo "<pre>";
   print_r($myarray);
echo "</pre>";
```

It is really annoying typing those just to get a readable format of an array.

Comment: what exactly do you call "shortcut" and why a function doesn't suit you?

Comment: Actually, the output of `print_r` already is in a readable format. It has linebreaks and indentation. You just dont see it because you display the content as HTML. You could simply look at the generated page source for the proper formatting.

Comment: There are far more tedious things to do than printing a readable array format in `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is the shortest:

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($arr,1),'</pre>';
```

The closing tag can also be omitted.

Comment: The closing tag can't be omitted, of course! What if he prints something and then continues rendering the page?

Comment: @Lo'oris Well, if `print_r` is being used, the rest of the layout of the page /usually/ won't matter.

Comment: @Lo'oris Okay, that wasn't phrased very eloquently. `print_r` is usually used for debugging. If one is debugging, he typically isn't worried about a layout breaking for one page load.

Comment: Depending on the layout. Sometimes you might output stuff at the top and then gracefully print all the page below that.

Comment: Furthermore, as I said to @Spudley, using `1` instead of `TRUE` is bad practice.

Comment: @Lo'oris You have to take into account what the OP is doing. It seems like he doesn't even want to write a function for what he's doing; he wants to debug and print something with as few keystrokes as possible. That's why I use `1` instead of true, omit spaces between the parameters, and mention that it's possible to omit the ending tag. The point of good practice is so that you and others can easily understand and maintain your code, but why should he care about good practice if the offending code is removed immediately after he finds the value of the variable?

Comment: because the more you do something, the more you do it again. And "not using a function" is stupid in this case.

Comment: Man that's still way too long. That's like what, 6 characters less to type? -.-

Comment: If you are using *CakePHP* then there's global function that does this: `pr($obj)`

Comment: Those commas should be periods... Or am I mistaken? I know, I know, this is an old post. Sorry.

Comment: @Curtis The commas are correct. They could be periods, but `echo` can take multiple arguments, which is the better practice (or at least it was five years ago).

Comment: @CaseyChu Thank you for this information! I should have Googled my thoughts before posting them.

Answer (score 28):

Nope, you'd just have to create your own function:

```
function printr($data) {
   echo "<pre>";
      print_r($data);
   echo "</pre>";
}
```

---

Apparantly, in 2018, people are still coming back to this question. The above would not be my current answer. I'd say: teach your editor to do it for you. I have a whole bunch of debug shortcuts, but my most used is `vardd` which expands to: `var_dump(__FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__, $VAR$);die();`

You can configure this in PHPStorm as a live template.

Comment: Format can be even more shorter - name function like "`pr`" - but still the best answer.

Comment: I added an additional param to let the script die if needed: 
function printpre($var,$die = 0){
    echo '<pre>',print_r($var,1),'</pre>';
    if($die == 1){
        die();
    }
}

Answer (score 14):

You can set the second parameter of [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) to `true` to get the output returned rather than directly printed:

```
$output = print_r($myarray, true);
```

You can use this to fit everything into one `echo` (don’t forget [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) if you want to print it into HTML):

```
echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars(print_r($myarray, true)), "</pre>";
```

If you then put this into a custom function, it is just as easy as using `print_r`:

```
function printr($a) {
    echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars(print_r($a, true)), "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Also, for more context and to retain the original function name as much as possible, you could name the function "pprint_r". This is entirely up to the developer, though.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not helpful, but if the array is the only thing that you'll be displaying, you could always set

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $myarray, true ) . '</pre>';
```

From the PHP.net [print_r() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

> When [the second] parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return the information rather than print it.

Answer (score 4):

If you use **VS CODE**, you can use : 
`Ctrl + Shift + P  -> Configure User Snippets -> PHP -> Enter`

After that you can input code to file php.json :

```
"Show variable user want to see": {
  "prefix": "pre_",
  "body": [
     "echo '<pre>';",
     "print_r($variable);",
     "echo '</pre>';"
  ],
  "description": "Show variable user want to see"
}
```

After that you save file **php.json**, then you return to the first file with any extension **.php** and input pre_ -> Enter
Done, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

teach your editor to do it-

after writing "pr_"  tab i get exactly

```
print("<pre>");
print_r($);
print("</pre>");
```

with the cursor just after the $

i did it on textmate by adding this snippet:

```
print("<pre>");
print_r(\$${1:});
print("</pre>");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using XDebug simply use

```
var_dump($variable);
```

This will dump the variable like `print_r` does - but nicely formatted and in a `<pre>`.

(If you don't use XDebug then `var_dump` will be as badly formated as `print_r` without `<pre>`.)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<pre/>"; print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both old and accepted, however, I'll just leave this here:

```
function dump(){
    echo (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') ? '<pre>' : '';
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg){
        echo preg_replace('#\n{2,}#', "\n", print_r($arg, true));
    }
    echo (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') ? '</pre>' : '';
}
```

Takes an arbitrary number of arguments, and wraps each in `<pre>` for CGI requests. In CLI requests it skips the `<pre>` tag generation for clean output.

```
dump(array('foo'), array('bar', 'zip'));
/*
CGI request                          CLI request

<pre>                                Array
Array                                (
(                                        [0] => foo
    [0] => foo                       )
)                                    Array
</pre>                               (
<pre>                                    [0] => bar
Array                                    [1] => zip
(                                    )
    [0] => bar
    [0] => zip
)
</pre>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure, that is not a shortcut.

Comment: No, it's not a shortcut in the context of a 'one liner', however having this readily accessible in a debug library or class makes it a shortcut. `Debug::dump($arg1, [$arg2, [$argN]]);`

Answer (score 1):

I just add function pr() to the global scope of my project.
For example, you can define the following function to global.inc (if you have) which will be included into your index.php of your site.  Or you can directly define this function at the top of index.php of root directory.

```
   function pr($obj)
   {
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r ($obj);
      echo "</pre>";
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write

`print_r($myarray);` //it will display you content of an array `$myarray`

`exit();` //it will not execute further codes after displaying your array

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can build a function / static class Method that does exactly that. I use Kohana which has a nice function called:

```
Kohana::Debug
```

That will do what you want. That's reduces it to only one line. A simple function will look like

```
function debug($input) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($input);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function printr($data)
{
   echo "<pre>";
      print_r($data);
   echo "</pre>";
}
```

And call your function on the page you need, don't forget to include the file where you put your function in for example: functions.php

```
include('functions.php');

printr($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for closing the php tag and then output the `<pre></pre>` as html, so PHP doesn't have to process it before echoing it:

```
?>

<pre><?=print_r($arr,1)?></pre>

<?php
```

That should also be faster (not notable for this short piece) in general. Using  can be used as shortcode for PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$people = array(
    "maurice"=> array("name"=>"Andrew",
                      "age"=>40,
                      "gender"=>"male"),
    "muteti" => array("name"=>"Francisca",
                      "age"=>30,
                      "gender"=>"Female")
               );
'<pre>'.
print_r($people).
'</pre>';

/*foreach ($people as $key => $value) {
    echo "<h2><strong>$key</strong></h2><br>";
    foreach ($value as $values) {
    echo $values."<br>";;
    }
}*/
//echo $people['maurice']['name'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally like to create my own function as has been stated above. However I like to add a few things to it so that if I accidentally leave in debugging code I can quickly find it in the code base. Maybe this will help someone else out.

```
function _pr($d) {
    echo "<div style='border: 1px solid#ccc; padding: 10px;'>";
    echo '<strong>' . debug_backtrace()[0]['file'] . ' ' . debug_backtrace()[0]['line'] . '</strong>';
    echo "</div>";
    echo '<pre>';
    if(is_array($d)) {
    print_r($d);
    } else if(is_object($d)) {
    var_dump($d);
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Shortcut key in **Sublime Text** Editor using **Preferences -> Key Bindings**

Now add below code on right-side of Key Bindings within square bracket []

```
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": { "contents": "echo \"<pre>\";\nprint_r(${0:\\$variable_to_debug});\necho \"</pre>\";\ndie();\n" }
}
```

Enjoy your **ctrl+shift+c** shortcut as a Pretty Print of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Download AutoHotKey program from the official website: [https://www.autohotkey.com/]

After Installation process, right click in any folder and you will get as the following image:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Rwz.png

Select AutoHotKey Script file, open it with notePad or any text editor Write the following in the file:

```
::Your_Shortcut::echo '<pre>';var_dump();echo '</pre>';exit();
```

the first ::Your_Shortcut means the shortcut you want, I choose for example vard.
Save the file.
Double-click on the file to run it, after that your shortcut is ready.
You can test it by write your shortcut and click space.

Answer (score -1):

For more simpler way

echo ""; print_r($test); exit();