# Azure media service php sdk create thumbnail

Tags: php, azure, cakephp-3.0, azure-media-services

I am using azure media service for uploading and encodeing the video. I am trying to get the thumbnail of video during encoding but always give error.
My code is here

```
function createThumbnail(MediaServicesRestProxy $restProxy, Asset $asset){
$mediaProcessor = $restProxy->getLatestMediaProcessor('Media Encoder Standard');
echo "Using Media Processor: {$mediaProcessor->getName()} version {$mediaProcessor->getVersion()}".PHP_EOL;
// 2.2 Create the Job; this automatically schedules and runs it
$outputAssetName = 'Encoded '.$asset->getName();
$outputAssetCreationOption = Asset::OPTIONS_NONE;
$taskBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><taskBody><inputAsset>JobInputAsset(0)</inputAsset><outputAsset assetCreationOptions="'.$outputAssetCreationOption.'" assetName="'.$outputAssetName.'">JobOutputAsset(0)</outputAsset></taskBody>';
$xmlThumbnail = '<?xml version="1.0 encoding="utf-8"?>
            <Thumbnail Size="50%,*" Type="Jpeg" Filename="{OriginalFilename}_{ThumbnailTime}.{DefaultExtension}">
              <Time Value="0:0:0"/>
              <Time Value="0:0:3" Step="0:0:0.25" Stop="0:0:10"/>
            </Thumbnail>';
$task = new Task($taskBody, $mediaProcessor->getId(), TaskOptions::NONE);
$task->setConfiguration($xmlThumbnail);
$job = new Job();
$job->setName('Thumbnail Creation Job');
$job = $restProxy->createJob($job, array($asset), array($task));
echo "Created Job with Id: {$job->getId()}".PHP_EOL;
// 2.3 Check to see if the Job has completed
$result = $restProxy->getJobStatus($job);
$jobStatusMap = array('Queued', 'Scheduled', 'Processing', 'Finished', 'Error', 'Canceled', 'Canceling');
while ($result != Job::STATE_FINISHED && $result != Job::STATE_ERROR && $result != Job::STATE_CANCELED) {
    echo "Job status: {$jobStatusMap[$result]}".PHP_EOL;
    sleep(5);
    $result = $restProxy->getJobStatus($job);
}
if ($result != Job::STATE_FINISHED) {
    echo "The job has finished with a wrong status: {$jobStatusMap[$result]}".PHP_EOL;
    exit(-1);
}
echo "Job Finished!".PHP_EOL;
// 2.4 Get output asset
$outputAssets = $restProxy->getJobOutputMediaAssets($job);
print_r($outputAssets);
$encodedAsset = $outputAssets[0];
echo "Thumbnail Asset encoded: name={$encodedAsset->getName()} id={$encodedAsset->getId()}".PHP_EOL;
return $encodedAsset;
}
```

I have take the refence from the .net code for creating thumbnail and php video encoding code to create the thumbnail using azure
Reference links
[Stackoverflow azure java sdk thumbnail example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732633/using-the-azure-media-services-thumbnail-task-preset-with-the-java-sdk)

and [Using the Azure Media Services Thumbnail Task Preset with the Java SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732633/using-the-azure-media-services-thumbnail-task-preset-with-the-java-sdk)

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: actually its return only error in xml response not telling what error

Comment: did you try debugging it and finding out, where it is breaking

Comment: you can debug it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785214/shortcut-for-echo-preprint-rmyarrayecho-pre , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124350/php-debugging-combine-foreach-and-exit ... you can use var_dump() , print_r() and exit() for it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/debugger.php